# Negative resistance - crystal

Tags: voltage, resistors, oscillator, crystal, negative-resistance

Why do we have the negative resistance concept in a crystal?

How does the crystal exhibit negative resistance?

I've read this [Link](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/examining-the-negative-resistance-of-a-quartz-crystal-oscillator/) and it seems to say that the amplifier is the one that causes the negative resistance due to positive feedback? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: This is an unfortunate conflation of two very distinct concepts. A crystal is a passive device that has a particular LC resonance with some finite Q (positive resistance, NOT negative). A crystal by itself will never exhibit negative resistance. You won't find any passive linear devices that does.  Meanwhile, a crystal oscillator can very well exhibit negative resistance at a particular node. This negative resistance provides the necessary amplification to sustain an oscillation. The negative resistance comes from the presence of an amplifier or an appropriately biased nonlinear passive.

Comment: This basically means, how much real resistance needs to be added to stop oscillation. If you need X ohms then basically the circuit has a margin of minus X ohms.

Comment: Why do we need to stop the oscillation ?

Comment: @Justme - Could you please explain with an answer in simple terms?

Comment: You only need to add resistance to stop the oscillation ... as a way to measure the negative resistance! The oscillation is what you want here, after all.

Comment: Could you please explain with an answer @user_1818839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Why do we have the negative resistance concept in a crystal?*

We don't as far as I know.

> *How does the crystal exhibit negative resistance?*

It doesn't as far as I know.

Talking about oscillators (an amplifier with appropriate phase-filter components) having a negative resistance is just an alternative (and somewhat overly-trendy) way of describing how an oscillator works. I don't particularly like this way of describing how an oscillator works so I would advise you to look at the crystal oscillator as per your recent questions on the subject that I have answered. Negative resistance doesn't bring anything new to the table and it somewhat dilutes what the main point about an oscillator is (IMHO).

> *Am I understanding it correctly?*

Impossible to say.

Comment: I was digging deep into the crystal oscillator topic and found an article which I have attached to the question. From there only, I got this query.

Comment: Yes, I read it and I don't like how they deal with the subject (negative resistance).

Comment: @Newbie are we done here (the article is pants and confuses the main issue of how a colpitts or pierce oscillator works)?

Comment: yes accepted the answer